# IntelliJ: evaluate lambda expression raises an compile error in debugging

Tags: intellij-idea, lambda

I'd like to evaluate code including lambda expression with Intellij 'Evaluate Code Fragment' feature. But then, Intellij raises an error `Unable to compile for target level 1.8. Need to run IDEA on java version at least 1.8, currently running on 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609`

The evaluating code is very simple as below.

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(1);
set.stream().map(v->v).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

My Intellij version is 14.0.3 and according to [official document](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/), version 14 supports lambda expression evaluation.

How can the feature be available?

[image]

Comment: Seems like this is a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132099 caused by the fact that IntelliJ is running on 1.6 (Apple JDK I guess) but the project uses JDK 1.8. So the solution is to make IntelliJ use JDK 1.8, but last I heard it there were some performance issues with that on Mac. However that may have already been fixed ....

Comment: Bohuslav's answer has worked for me so far. To change the JDK, I followed [these instructions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827547-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under). On my Mac, I changed Info.plist to be: `<key>JVMVersion</key>
      <string>1.8*</string>`. Seems to be okay. Can execute lambdas in debug mode now.

Answer (score 1):

Putting together the comments from [adrian lange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2865154/adrian-lange) and [Bohuslav Burghardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1291150/bohuslav-burghardt), either upgrade to the latest IntelliJ 14.1 which comes bundled with Java 1.8, or switch your current IntelliJ to use Java 1.8. See bug [IDEA-132099](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132099).

To switch to Java 1.8:

1. Install [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
2. Change IntelliJ to use Java 8. See [these instructions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879).[image: Project structure]

Comment: The answer is good enough if you just need your project to be compiled in java 8. But to use java 8 syntax in watcher/ evaluate expression I had to update IDEA_JDK and IDEA_JDK_64 to point to java 8 (this is mentioned in the blogs referred in the answer anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Even after applying above defined project specific settings on IntelliJ as well as Eclipse, it was still failing for me !

**what worked for me was addition of maven plugin with source and target with 1.8 setting in POM XML:**

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.abc.sparkcore.JavaWordCount</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can switch runtime version of JDK:

1. Start the IDE, Help | Find Action (Ctrl+Shift+A or Cmd+Shift+A on Mac), type "Switch IDE Boot JDK", press Enter.
2. Start the IDE, use Help | Find Action (Ctrl+Shift+A or Cmd+Shift+A on Mac), type "Switch IDE Boot JDK", press Enter.
   Switch IDE Boot JDK dialog appears. Select the version from the drop-down or click "…" entry to specify the custom location.

Answer (score 0):

```
Unable to compile for target level 1.8...Currently running on version 1.6
```

My guess is that your project is being run on a version of Java that doesn't support lambdas. Make sure you have Java 8 installed, and also make sure to change your project level to use Java 8, like so:
[image]
Notice that it explicitly mentions lambdas