# Intellij Idea 14.1.1problems evaluating lambda expressions

Tags: intellij-idea, lambda, java-8

I am running evaluate expression for lambda expressions in my IDE,Intellij Idea 14.1.1.It gives me the message Unable to compile for target level 1.8. Need to run IDEA on java version at least 1.8, currently running on 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716

The code compiles just fine and runs fine too,only when i do evaluate expression while debugging do i get this problem.
I have checked all the compiler setting they are all set to 1.8.

Any ideas what setting i need to change?

Comment: If it compiles, this implies that you have a Java 8 JDK.  Do you have this configured in IntelliJ as well?

Comment: ya have it in the preferences,runs on the ide just fine.really confused why evaluate expression fails

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555302/intellij-evaluate-lambda-expression-raises-an-compile-error-in-debugging#comment47270927_29555302

Comment: You are correct @BohuslavBurghardt ,here is the issue link alos https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132099#tab=Comments

Answer (score 0):

1. Install java 8;
2. From Project Structure -> Project Settings ->
   Project: select java 1.8 as Project SDK; select 8 - Lamdas, type
   annotations etc.
3. From Settings -> Language & Frameworks ->
   JavaScript    -> Libraries: from the libraries list, make sure
   ECMAScript 6 is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Open pom.xml and enter Java configuration inside build:

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```